# Bluetooth not working properly on 18.04 LTS Lenovo Y50-70

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo

I installed ubuntu on my Y50-70 laptop, and tried practically everything I found on the internet.

At first glance it seems fine, it searches and finds my BT devices, but it just doesn't pair them. When I click on a device it says: "Not Set Up"

I've tried with blueman and other cli methods i've found and still no luck.

It seems that only windows knows how to handle the Bluetooth drivers of this particular machine.

for now, I've reinstalled ubuntu so that my other attempts will not interfere, and would like your help to see if there's anything to do.

rfkill list - output:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

edit: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb -output:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

edit 2: output for: dmesg | grep -i blue

```
[   39.467292] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   39.467305] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   39.467308] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   39.467309] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   39.467311] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   41.284394] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710010002030d00
[   42.020504] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
[   42.191401] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[   42.206397] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   45.853135] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   45.853136] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   45.853139] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   99.170615] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   99.170619] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   99.170622] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Also please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: Search for this `hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f`. That must be the problem.

Comment: where to search for it? @Pilot6

Comment: In google for example ;-)

Comment: haha, thought you meant in the output... thanks for the help so far. unfortunately I still can't find anything useful

Comment: There is no other way to find a solution. There must be some bug with loading firmware. What is the kernel version? `uname -a`

Comment: Linux yp-Y50-70 5.0.0-27-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 03:00:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux